# In GoogleApp Spreadsheet, how do I make onEdit event handler react to drag copying?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

My onEdit event handler fires just fine when I edit spreadsheet cell manually, or when I paste into it by Ctrl+V, but completely ignores when I do 'drag-copying'.

'drag-copying' is when you point the mouse to cell's lower right corner, the one marked with little square, then hold left mouse button down, then move the mouse down. When you do so, Spreadsheet will copy cell's value to every cell below, down to mouse pointer's current position.

I want my code in onEdit event handler to process every change of cell values.

But it doesn't gets called at all!

Please point me to how to do it right or tell me it's not possible.

Comment: I guess this should be posted as a bug. since clearly the onEdit event should fire with this.

Comment: The problem is no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug and has been reported on [Apps Script Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=399)

So, to answer your question: No, it is not currently possible.

Best,
Anton

Comment: While the issue referred is still open, at this time onEdit works fine for drag-copying.

Comment: I just tried this and the onEdit only fires for the first item in a drag-copy.  Rubén, you have tried this and it fires for every row for you?

Comment: In the linked issue Google just updated it to clarify how the onEdit() works.  It fires per edit, not per row so you need to look at the active range to see what was changed.